# Why do I have a red dot in every photo?

Tags: lens, troubleshooting, artifacts, hot-pixels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my camera showing a lot of stuck red and white pixels?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14889/why-is-my-camera-showing-a-lot-of-stuck-red-and-white-pixels)

Every picture that I took today have a red dot on the same place in every photo.  It looks like a monitor "pixel error". 
Is just the lens dirty or did something bad happen to my cam?

[Here some samples.](http://www.zangzing.com/gsharp/the-red-dot-visitor) Best mode to detect the dot is download the picture in original size (click the (i) then download)