# Bright dots on all images

Tags: sensor, equipment-damage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my camera showing a lot of stuck red and white pixels?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14889/why-is-my-camera-showing-a-lot-of-stuck-red-and-white-pixels)

Recently I noticed that on every picture I take, there are some tiny (close to pixel size) bright dots (mostly white or red), always at the same location.  The dots appear even if I take an otherwise completely dark picture with the lens cap on.  Their brightness is independent of shutter speed, but they do get brighter at higher ISO settings.

What is this caused by?  Is it sensor damage?  If yes, what could have caused it?  Is there anything I can do about this?

The camera is a Nikon D60.

This is what the dots look like, shot with the lens cap on, 1/4000 s, ISO 1600 (magnified image):

[image]

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfhSO.jpg) is the full image, with the location of these two dots marked.  (Note: it has been recompressed to JPEG.)